# <action method="setTemplate">page/1column.phtml VS <update handle="page_one_column">

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, theme

```
<update handle="page_one_column" />
```

**These both set the template to 1page. Is there any reason to use one over the other?**

```
<reference name="root">
  <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

I have noticed that both of these seem to have the same effect (making the page use the `1column.phtml template`) but I'm sure there are subtle differences that only a Magento expert would know about. `Is there any reason to use one over the other`? I like the `flexibility of using the update handle`, but it seems like it could have unintended repercussions.

The first question that comes to mind is: does the `page_one_column` handle override the `page_two_columns_left` handle that is already there? `Could this cause the page to have both handles?`

Edit[Clarification]: I understand that  `<page_one_column>` is a layout handle, and it can be "applied" by calling `<update handle="page_one_column" />`. What I don't understand (and want to know) is if this can cause any negative side-effects. I myself can't think of any edge cases where this might break something, but it seems like they could exist. I can't really know for sure without digging deep into the code and trying to break stuff.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the purpose of `<update handle="some_name">` you can look at following magento file:

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog_msrp.xml

you can create your own handle

```
<my_handle_blabla>
    <!-- some layout -->
</my_handle_blabla>
```

Then you can add your handle anywhere `<update handle="my_handle_blabla" />` It's like **echo $property**

Comment: This is correct and useful information, but doesn't quite answer my question. I have clarified the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use either handle or reference root and set the template yourself.

Both of them do the exact same thing. A layout (e.g. catalog_product_view) can include as many  as needed. It won't break anything.

---

Look at handle is a proper way to practice code re-use (or a function call for lack of better words).

For example, you have your own module that render 2 different routes

```
module/controller/action1
module/controller/action2
```

So you have 2 layouts accordingly

```
module_controller_action1
module_controller_action2
```

In both layout, says you have to include CSS/JS for both of these pages

You can do it this way in your layout file

```
<module_controller_action1>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <name>css/module/style.css</name>
            <params/>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/module/script.js</name>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <!-- DECLARE BLOCK -->
    </reference>
</module_controller_action1>

<module_controller_action2>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <name>css/module/style.css</name>
            <params/>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/module/script.js</name>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <!-- DECLARE BLOCK -->
    </reference>
</module_controller_action2>
```

Or you can use update handle mechanism to make it neater this way

```
<module_controller_assets>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <name>css/module/style.css</name>
            <params/>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/module/script.js</name>
        </action>
    </reference> 
</module_controller_assets>

<module_controller_action1>
    <update handle="module_controller_assets" />
    <reference name="content">
        <!-- DECLARE BLOCK -->
    </reference> 
</module_controller_action1>

<module_controller_action2>
    <update handle="module_controller_assets" />
    <reference name="content">
        <!-- DECLARE BLOCK -->
    </reference> 
</module_controller_action2>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any reason to use one over the other

Not really as far as I know. They do the same thing. `<update handle="page_one_column" />` is just shortcut that has been hard-coded in `Mage_Page`. See `app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/config.xml`.

The `setTemplate` (`Mage_Core_Block_Template::setTemplate`) method in your example simply sets `root`'s template to `page/1column.phtml`, which is configured in the `config.xml` file above.